# YouTube channel analytics in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, youtube, youtube-data-api

How to get my youtube channel analytics data in power bi?
I mean my:

- Views
- Likes
- watch times
- etc
  All data that I see on my channel and video analytics, I need to create a dashboard for my YouTube channel analytics.

I have been searching on YouTube and Microsoft documentation but have not found any help there.

Comment: There is probably a better answer so i am posting here, i use sync with to get the youtube data to google sheets and the google sheets connector in power bi to get the data into powerbi, I did you this https://github.com/migueesc123/YoutubeAnalytics but it was about 5-6 years ago

Comment: https://hevodata.com/learn/youtube-analytics-power-bi-integration/